# Trying to implement AsyncTask with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

So i'm trying to implement AsyncTask on my NewsParser and i thought i got it, but i can't run the activity, i get the following errors on LogCat:

```
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.igestao/com.example.igestao.Noticias}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:110)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.example.igestao.Noticias$DownloadFilesTask.onPreExecute(Noticias.java:73)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.example.igestao.Noticias.onCreate(Noticias.java:58)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-11 16:15:24.572: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  ... 11 more
```

This is what i got on my MainActivity:

```
public class Noticias extends ListActivity {

static final String URL = "http://loc.grupolusofona.pt/index.php/?format=feed";
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
static final String KEY_PUBDATE = "pubDate";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Spanned>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Spanned>>();
private DownloadFilesTask download;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_noticias);

    download = new DownloadFilesTask(null);
    download.execute();
}



private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    private Context context;
    public DownloadFilesTask (Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading1", "Loading2", true);
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(); 
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);



        String data[] = new String[nl.getLength()];
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

            HashMap<String, Spanned> map = new HashMap<String, Spanned>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            data[i] = getTagValue("pubDate", e);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.UK);
            Date date = null;

            try {
                date = sdf.parse(data[i]); 
                String timeOfDay = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date); 
                java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
                java.sql.Timestamp timeStampNow = new Timestamp((new java.util.Date()).getTime());  

                long secondDiff = timeStampNow.getTime() / 1000 - timeStampDate.getTime() / 1000;
                int minuteDiff = (int) (secondDiff / 60);
                int hourDiff = (int) (secondDiff / 3600);
                int dayDiff = daysBetween(date, new Date());
                if (dayDiff > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Há " + dayDiff + " dia(s), às " + timeOfDay); 
                    data[i] = ("Há " + dayDiff + " dia(s), às " + timeOfDay);


                } else if (hourDiff > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Há " + hourDiff + " hora(s), às " + timeOfDay);
                    data[i] = ("Há " + hourDiff + " hora(s), às " + timeOfDay);


                } else if (minuteDiff > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Há " + minuteDiff + " minuto(s), às " + timeOfDay);
                    data[i] = ("Há " + minuteDiff + " minuto(s), às " + timeOfDay);


                } else if (secondDiff > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Há " + secondDiff + " segundo(s), às " + timeOfDay);
                    data[i] = ("Há " + secondDiff + " segundo(s), às " + timeOfDay);

                }
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            map.put(KEY_TITLE, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE)));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC)));
            map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, Html.fromHtml(data[i]));
            map.put(KEY_LINK, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK)));

            menuItems.add(map);

        }//endFOR
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        adapter_listview();


        //onClick gets URL from ListView and opens it
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();
            Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            in.setData(Uri.parse(link));
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });


    }
}








private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element e) { 

    NodeList nlList = e.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();

}

public static int daysBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate) { 

    int daysBetween = 0;
    while (startDate.before(endDate)) {
        startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + 86400000);
        daysBetween++;
    }
    return daysBetween;

}

public void adapter_listview(){

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems, R.layout.linhafeed, 
            new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_PUBDATE, KEY_LINK },
            new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.desc, R.id.pub, R.id.link });


    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Could someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong ?
I've been through the Tutorials on AsyncTask, but to no effect here.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`download = new DownloadFilesTask(null);`

In the above line of code you are **passing null**, that **shouldNot be done.**

**-** Pass `Activity_Name.this` instead of `null`.

**Eg:**

```
download = new DownloadFilesTask(Noticias.this);
download.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `null` as the context to the AsyncTask. Instead pass `getBaseContext()` or `this`.

Answer (score 1):

```
download = new DownloadFilesTask(null);
    download.execute();// this wrong method you pass null
```

instead of use this one

```
download = new DownloadFilesTask();
        download.execute(this);
```